# pygame: get the current time of the music

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, pygame

Is there any way in pygame (Python 3) to get the "real" current playtime of the playing music file? pygame.mixer.music.get_pos() does only return how long pygame is playing the file. But when I skip forward, pygame.mixer.music.get_pos() returns the "wrong" value. So when I play the music e.g. for 10 seconds and skip to minute 1:00, then pygame.mixer.music.get_pos() returns 10 seconds instead of 1:10 minutes.

Is there any way to get the "real" current play time of the music?

(I need this for a tkinter scale bar and time label)

Comment: Skipping to another time stamp, you could look at the current position and account for the offset yourself, storing the real time along with the music item.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I understand what you mean by the "real" current playtime. In your example, it sounds like you play 10 seconds, and skip ahead 50 seconds to the 1 minute mark in the song. Then you want it to display 1:10, but that seems like the total of time playing music and the current position. Is that what you want or am I misunderstanding the example?

Answer (score 1):

use pygame.mixer.music.get_pos() / 1000

if I'm not mistaken I read that get_pos() returns a value in milliseconds

[I tested it manually with a song here, and yes it works perfectly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o9XEn.png)

Comment: Welcome, @johndoe! It's generally not very helpful to post screenshots since it's hard to extract the code you used and in this case, we can't even see the code (context for your snippet in the text portion of your answer).

Comment: Also, it seems you just responded with the exact code the original poster cited not working for them. If you really are convinced that code already works for them and they just don't understand, then that requires some explanation why they appeared to get a different result than you to shed new light on the situation (not simply contradict them). And dividing by 100 doesn't seem relevant to the question.